# PHP TCP Socket on Linux - Forking the connection

Tags: php, linux, sockets, tcp, fork

My current setup has a PHP socket listener on Windows, which listens on port 5555. Every time there's a new connection, the server needs to send a large amount of data through that newly connected socket. Usually sending that data takes about 10 seconds, and within that time, the program is basically stuck and cannot accept anymore socket connections until it's done syncing.

My goal is to make the newly connected sockets run on the background, so that syncing doesn't hang the main listener.
I found a php function called **pcntl_fork** to fork the process and it sounds like it does exactly what I need it to do, except I am not sure it will work properly with sockets.

Will this setup help me do the following?
- Main CLI program listens for all incoming TCP connections on port 5555
- Once device is connected, it sends data back and fourth to the client for 30 seconds.
- Within the 30 seconds, few more devices connect, and start receiving data for another 30 seconds each.

Will the port be open for multiple clients at the same time and is that even possible?

In the ideal situation, each sync process takes 30 seconds, and if 5 clients connect at the same time, it will take 30 seconds in total for all of the devices to receive data, and not 2min 30sec like it is right now.

Thanks

Comment: check this http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world